# Atlassian Bitbucket reserved keywords

Tags: repository, bitbucket, keyword, reserved

I have searched high and low for a list of reserved keywords that are not allowed when naming repositories using Atlassian Bitbucket Data Center.

The reason is that if I name a repository 'repos' it fails to load the page properly when looking at commits in that repo.  And I believe it is because the URL to view the commit is:

```
https://www.blah.blah.blah/bitbucket/projects/XXXX/repos/repos/commits/<commitid>/common.sh
```

The second 'repos' in the URL is the name of my repo, but the preceding 'repos' in the path makes me think I can't name it that way since I get an error when trying to view the commit.

Anyone have any experience with this?  Thanks in advance!

I have proven that naming the repo anything other than 'repos' works, so it's obvious I can't name it that. But I am seeking a definitive explanation if it exists anywhere within Atlassian documentation.

Thanks!!